# RegEx searching for a exact word in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to find exact word using regEx. My program gives incorrect ouptut :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String patternStr =  "3";

    Pattern patternMatcher = Pattern.compile("(\\s|\\W)?"+patternStr+"(\\s|\\W)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    strList.add("3? Message");
    strList.add("This is 3 Message ");
    strList.add("Hi 33.");
    strList.add("Hi [3]");
    strList.add("Hi 3!!!");


    for(String str : strList) {
        Matcher matcher = patternMatcher.matcher(str);
        System.out.println(">> "+matcher.find());
    }
  }
```

The o/p is :

```
  >> true
>> true
>> true
>> true
>> true

But its supposed to be 
 >> true
    >> true
    >> false
    >> true
    >> true
```

Can some tell me what I am doing wrong here ? It works fine for word.length > 1 For ex :

```
   String patternStr =  "Hello";

    Pattern patternMatcher = Pattern.compile("(\\s|\\W)?"+patternStr+"(\\s|\\W)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    strList.add("hello? Message");
    strList.add("This is Hello Message ");
    strList.add("Hi Hellos.");
    strList.add("Hi [Hello]");
    strList.add("Hi Hello!!!");


    for(String str : strList) {
        Matcher matcher = patternMatcher.matcher(str);
        System.out.println(">> "+matcher.find());
    }
  }

The o/p is :
>> true
>> true
>> false
>> true
>> true
```

But for a letter it gives wrong o/p. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here ??

Comment: Why not just use `Pattern.compile("\\b"+Pattern.quote(patternStr)+"\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`? Your regex fails to check the initial boundary because `(\\s|\\W)?` is optional.

Comment: It's because as per your regex `3` after `3` is allowed. It will output `true` for input `This is HelloHello`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is matching any non-alphanumeric character on both sides of the 3, but optionally on the left. Therefore, it's ok that there is a 3 to the left of the 3 in the third case, because the match is optional.

```
33.
```

`.` is not alphanumeric, and the match on the first 3 is optional. - it matches

```
Hellos
```

`s` **is** alphanumeric, and does not match the regex.

You can also use [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) to test your regular expressions.

Comment: To test Java regex, one should prefer [Regex Planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) or [OCPsoft Regex Tester](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/) to regexr.com.